# How to force a class have one type of fields

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, types

I am writing a java code.I have an abstract class `A`. Any user can extend a class from `A` -lets say `B`- and could use it.

What I want to do is force the user to only add `String` types to class `B`. Why I want this is because later I will dynamically get and set class `B`'s fields, and they have to be in String format.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, as already mentioned, normally you wouldn't want to do this, so the first suggestion is to revise your application design.

From pure Java coding standpoint, you can use reflection in abstract class constructor to check on field types, so the user of you class will never run the code if his class does not meet your requirements

```
public abstract class A {
    public A() {
        for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getType() != String.class) {
                throw new RuntimeException("only String type of fields are allowed");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Be very carefull and keep in mind all the downsides of the approach and using reflection as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , this is the only way to check I think.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible, you cannot (functionally) impose limitations on future fields. You'll just have to document it or revise your approach alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to *nearly* do what you want is to demand a getter and setter for the field.

```
public abstract A {
  public String getField ();
  public void setField (String value);
}
```